# Stop unauthorized attempts to access port 1433

Tags: sql, firewall

I'm picking up huge amounts of attempts to access our SQL database through port 1433 (Windows Server 2008).

How do I configure a firewall rule that only allows access from the box IP only so that the only way to access the SQL is when logged in by RDC.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have more luck with networking questions on Serverfault, if in a professional capacity, or Superuser otherwise. Also details on the OS version/release would help :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how it works.  Your going to want to create a firewall rule with an exception for port 1433.  Then you are going to have to figure out what your Scope is.  On the rule you'll see a tab named Scope where you will want to modify the Remote IP Address section.  You will want to add your static IP address or range there to allow connection.  I am unaware of any way to dynamically grab the logged in RDP IP and apply that to an SQL firewall rule.